# detecting all the bluetooth devices present in an area including the devices which are already paired

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluetooth, android-sdk-2.1

I am willing to generate a list which has the list of all the bluetooth enabled devices in the phone's vicinity. The code which I have discovers the devices which are not paired. Is there a way to retrieve the devices which are also paired (if they fall with the vicinity)

The code which discovers all the devices in the vicinity is as follows

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth_connection);

    final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


    final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
    { 
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            String action = intent.getAction(); 
            // When discovery finds a device 
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) 
            {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent 
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(
            BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            tv.append(device.getName() + "-"+ device.getAddress()+"\n"); 
            }
        }


    };
    String aDiscoverable = BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE;
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(aDiscoverable),DISCOVERY_REQUEST);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND); 
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); 
    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
}
```

Can any one help me out in adding the code which discovers even the devices which are paired.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = adapter.getBondedDevices();
    for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
      tv.append(device);
    }
```

I haven't tested this.  It's from [this tutorial](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/50.html).

Comment: When I used the above code, I am still getting the paired devices only and not all the devices...Can you give me further insight to this problem